# Angularjs regex pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am not that good in regex and here is my problem i need to create a regex with the following criteria **Minimum of 10 characters with uppercase letters, lowercase letters, at least one number, at least one special character and not matches the username.**

and here is my regex `/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%]).{10,50})/`

and below is my html

`<input ng-model="Form.Account.Username" name="AccountUsername" type="text" ng-focus ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=16 placeholder="Your Account Username" ng-blur="makeItDirty(Checkout.AccountUsername)" required ng-ensure-unique ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$/" />
<input ng-model="Form.Account.Password" name="AccountPassword" ng-focus type="password" ng-blur="makeItDirty(Checkout.AccountPassword)" required placeholder="Your Account Password" ng-pattern="/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%]).{10,50})/" />`

the only criteria that i can't catch is make the password invalid if the password matches or contains the username.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job. While regular expressions are great for the first part of your problem (enforcing a certain level of password complexity); it's a terrible solution for the second part of your problem.  Don't use a regex when a simple `.indexOf()` will do the job.  I know it's nice to do everything in a single pattern/check, but your best option is to separate them into two checks. One runs through the regex to enforce the password rules while the second check ensures their username is not a substring of the password.